# Not able to post data to server and not geting any respons from server

Tags: java, angular, typescript

I am not able to post data to server. On clicking button i submit form and i am getting data into api service class but it's not sending to server which place somewhere else. I am going to give all detail here under:I have other apis method in service class they are working well , but when i want to post data, i am not able to post data and neither getting any response from server while checking database no entry there:

service.ts : orgId is string which is pass in url as foreign key to add adresspostmodel , and data is json object. I am using data:any(reason the actual table has more field which auto generated). when i use postman the api and all working well with same url and json object as i giving hereunder:

service.ts :

```
public postFormData(orgId: string, data: any): Observable<AdressModel> {  
   return this.http.post<any>(`${this.ApiUrl}/${orgId}/addresses`, data).pipe(
   tap(response => console.log(response)), catchError(this.handleError));
```

}

```
onSubmit(){
this.data =
  {
    "city": "test",
    "email": "test@gemiil.com",
    "name": "test2",
    "recipient": "test",
    "street": "test",
    "zipCode": "12345"
  }
 
this.ApiService.postFormData(this.organizationId, this.data);
```

}

this.data actually i am getting data from form, but here form example i am giving you json mock object, which is also correct, here is my json object and whole api in console both api , och json object in console is looking correct for me :
api data in console

```
{
```

"city":"test",
"email":"test@gemiil.com",
"name":"test2",
"recipient":"test",
"street":"test",
"zipCode":"12345"
}

Can anyone help to find what's problem is there with logic?

Answer (score 0):

Observable are lazy in nature, so you must subscribe to make it to send request to server.

`this.ApiService.postFormData(this.organizationId, this.data).subscribe((resp) =>  console.log(resp));`